# how to use telnet-client plugin in ionic2

Tags: ionic2, telnet

I want to establish a tcp/ip connection and send data from my ionic2 app,so i have gone through some plugins and found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/telnet-client) but ,i don't know how to implement it.i installed it using these commands `npm install telnet-client
npm install -g telnet-client` as per the link i have to use something like`var telnet = require('telnet-client');` I tried with this

```
import { telnet } from 'telnet-client';
let connnection = new telnet();
```

but got this error,

> **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_telnet_client**.telnet is not a constructor

I would like to know how to implement it in ionic2

> colud anyone please suggest someother plugin to send data from my app via wifi

Comment: You need to find a Cordova plugin.This is a node.js module.

Comment: could you please suggest any cordova telnet-client plugin

Comment: Please see about this? https://github.com/blocshop/sockets-for-cordova

Comment: i will look in to that

Comment: i have installed that cordova plugin ,its under "plugins" folder of my project.But, i couldn't import it

Comment: I tried something like '(<any>window).plugins.Socket.open();' got error 'Cannot read property 'Socket' of undefined'

Comment: even like this "import { Socket } from  '@ionic-native/Socket'; " got some error like "Cannot find module @ionic-native/Socket"

Comment: Does above plugin OK for your task? If yes then I'll explain how to use it.

Comment: as i mentioned in the question, my goal is to make a tcp/ip connection and send data / receive data from my ionic2 app.so, i hope this plugin will help me in that context

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [this plugin](https://github.com/blocshop/sockets-for-cordova) like below.This is none native plugin.Hence no  `import` or `providers`.

**Note:** You cannot test this on the browser.You have to use either device or emulator.

```
declare let window: any;

@Component({
  ...
})
export class TestPage {

  ...

  isOpened() {
   if (window.Socket.state == window.Socket.State.OPENED) {
       console.log("Socket is opened");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Cannot find name 'Socket'

Comment: Please see the update above and you cannot test this on the browser.You have to use either device or emulator.

Comment: i checked on a device i get error like cannot find state of undefined